# MuleClient send cannot route event via endpoint

Tags: mule

I'm stuck with a problem with MuleClient Send. I would like to simulate SMS sending with a https endpoint, but I'm always getting this error message:

```
...MwException: ...messaging.MwMessageList@5c2f4f8b[messageList=[...messaging.MwMessage@260f5df5[severity=ERROR,code=-1,text=Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://localhost:65439/sms_fogad.php, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=smsHttpsConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=6b26a8dc
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.https.localhost.65439.sms.fogad.php', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=GET}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}. Message payload is of type: GetMethod,sourceSystemCode=SMS_SERVER]]]
    at ....connector.sms.dao.SmsDaoImpl.send(SmsDaoImpl.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.send(Unknown Source)
    at hu....app.esb.service.util.UtilSmsSendSmsGw1Impl.service(UtilSmsSendSmsGw1Impl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:91)
    at ....app.esb.aspect.EsbWsAspect.aroundService(EsbWsAspect.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.service(Unknown Source)
    at ....app.esb.service.cdp.handler.CDPHandlerImpl.process(CDPHandlerImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.AbstractEntryPointResolver.invokeMethod(AbstractEntryPointResolver.java:151)
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.ReflectionEntryPointResolver.invoke(ReflectionEntryPointResolver.java:121)
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:39)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:343)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:86)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:77)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:126)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:61)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:242)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:160)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:122)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:192)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:185)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:184)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is the code snippet which tries to send the message:

```
try {
        muleClient = new MuleClient(RequestContext.getEventContext().getMuleContext());
        logger.debug("messageMap: " + messageMap);
        result = muleClient.send("vm://smsEndpoint", messageMap, messageProperties);
        logger.debug("result: " + result.getPayload());
        if (result.getExceptionPayload() != null) {
            mwMessageList.addMessage(MwMessage.createError(String.valueOf(result.getExceptionPayload().getCode()), result.getExceptionPayload()
                    .getMessage(), SystemCode.SMS_SERVER));
            throw new MwException(mwMessageList);
        } else {                
            String smsResult = result.getPayload(String.class);
            if (smsResult.contains("OK")) {
                logger.info("SMS_ID: " + smsResult.split("\\s")[0] + ", CORRELATION_ID: " + correlationId);
            } else {
                mwMessageList.addMessage(MwMessage.createError("", smsResult, SystemCode.SMS_SERVER));
                throw new MwException(mwMessageList);
            }
        }
    } catch (MuleException e) {
        mwMessageList.addMessage(MwMessage.createError(String.valueOf(e.getMessageCode()), e.getDetailedMessage(), SystemCode.SMS_SERVER));
        throw new MwException(mwMessageList);
    }
```

messageMap and messageProperties contain correct data, I'm sure.
Error occurs at this line:

```
result = muleClient.send("vm://smsEndpoint", messageMap, messageProperties);
```

smsEndpoint is defined in an external flow:

```
<https:connector name="smsHttpsConnector">
    <https:tls-key-store path="${mule.home}/conf/something/ssl-keys/${ssl.truststore}" keyPassword="${ssl.truststore.password}" storePassword="${ssl.truststore.password}"/>
</https:connector>

<flow name="SmsServiceFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="smsEndpoint" 
        exchange-pattern="request-response" >
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Received in VM: #[payload]" level="INFO" />
    <https:outbound-endpoint path="${sms.path}" 
        host="${sms.host}" port="${sms.port}" exchange-pattern="request-response" 
        method="GET" connector-ref="smsHttpsConnector" disableTransportTransformer="true" transformer-refs="mapToHttpGetRequestTransformer">
    </https:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>

<custom-transformer name="mapToHttpGetRequestTransformer" class="hu....connector.transformer.MapToHttpGetRequestTransformer" />
```

I have debugged it step by step, but the only thing I notice is exceptionPayload being filled when result gets value.

The value of result after the erroneus line:

SmsDaoImpl: result: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@6a33f2cf

I'm using Mule 3.4 runtime and MuleStudio 3.5, any help would be appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you connect to the https://localhost:65439/sms_fogad.php address with a web browser or some other http client? Have you checked for error messages in the server logs for that php application?

Comment: Yes I can. It is only a php page for displaying the result in text format, so there is no error in it.

Comment: I meant that can you see if the php server receives the calls from Mule and logs some error. Also, please include a full stack trace for the Mule error. "Failed to route" doesn't really tell anything about the cause of failure.

Comment: I have updated the question with the stack trace. There is no php server, it is just an emulation for the real system, but previous tests worked correctly with it, so the error is not related to that page.

Comment: Do you get the call in the PHP? can you log the request in the php page and attach it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I found the problem. Turns out I was using Mule Standalone server with 3.2 runtime, which caused the problem, because the mock server was written using version 3.4.